# How to edit and tag a video in iPhone app programmatically?

Tags: iphone, video

In iPhone app, how do we edit a recorded video programmatically? 
Is there any particular API to edit video frame-by-frame?

Also, I want to tag a video frame with some text. Like we do for the photos on FB, only in this case it must do the tagging on video. While playing the video, tags must be visible.

Any help will helpful...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188) is the API you are probably looking for. `AVFoundation` is not just a Media-player as you might think. It is also capable of video/audio editing.

A really good source with more info and examples are the WWDC sessions of the last year.

Comment: ok..I will check out the AVFoundation class.

Comment: Also, do you know of any method to tag the recorded videos?

Comment: Imo that is not possible without to render them directly into the video or by creating a custom video container format. That's just what i think.